# Changing 'Location' in 'Add New Item' dialog box with Visual Studio SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to modify Location path in Visual Studio 'Add New Item' dialog using Visual Studio SDK.

The default path is the path of the project but I want to change this path to a different one.

I've been digging through the SDK documentation but I could not find an interface or event for that. If anyone knows how to do it I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to change the path. You can however just right click the folder you want the new item to be added to and select the "Add New Item" entry from the context menu.

Comment: I want to write a CMake project helper addin. This means that my project files are in completely different place than the code and I want to automate the process of finding the correct path. I know the user can just find the correct path by navigating the filesystem but I would like to have the addin do it for him.